# $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \frac{(1+n^{2})^{s}}{1+(n-y)^{r}}\leq C$ for all $y\in \mathbb R$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Fix $y\in \mathbb R$ and $s>1.$

Consider the series:
$$I(y)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \frac{(1+n^{2})^{s}}{1+(n-y)^{r}}.$$

> **My Question is**: Can we choose $r$ large enough so that $I(y)< C$ for all $y\in \mathbb R$; where $C$ is some constant ? If not, for a  given $y,$ can we find $r$ so that, $I(y)<\infty;$ and what can we about values of $I(y)$ ? (I mean, how it looks in terms of $y$)

Comment: Where do you get these series from? Another [recent one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/888809/) was similar.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we choose $r$ large enough so that $I(y)<C$ for all $y\in \mathbb R$.

No, because when $y$ is an integer, $I(y)\ge (1+y^2)^s$ (just from the term $n=y$).

> For a given $y$, can we find $r$ so that, $I(y)<\infty $

*This* you can do independently of $y$: just let $r>2s+1$. Observe that the terms of the series are $O(n^{2s-r})$.

> what can we about values of $I(y)$ ?

Periodic function...

Comment: thanks lot; Since you have observed to me that, $I(y)\geq (1+y^{2})^{s};$ o.k, now my question is, can expect to find some constant $C$ so that, $I(y)\leq C (1+y^{2})^{s}, $ for all $y\in \mathbb R$ ?; would you please tell me a bit in this direction, thanks a lot?