# Can we expect to find some constant $C$; so that, $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \frac{1}{1+(n-y)^{2}} <C$ for all $y\in \mathbb R;$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Fix $y\in \mathbb R;$ and consider the series:
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}\frac{1}{1+(n-y)^{2}}.$$

> **My Question is**: Can we expect to find some constant $C$; so that, 
>   $$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \frac{1}{1+(n-y)^{2}} <C$$ for all $y\in \mathbb R;$ If yes, How ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{[y]} \frac{1}{1+(n-y)^2} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{[y]-1} \frac{1}{1+(n-y)^2} + \frac{1}{1+([y]-y)^2} \leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{1} \frac{1}{1+n^2} + 1 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\sum_{[y]+1}^{n=+\infty} \frac{1}{1+(n-y)^2} = \sum_{[y]+2}^{n=+\infty} \frac{1}{1+(n-y)^2} + \frac{1}{1+([y]+1 -y)^2} \leq \sum_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2} + 1 
\end{align}

Thus $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+(n-y)^2} \leq 2 \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} + 2 = \frac{\pi^2}{3}+2$

Comment: Liu Gang; thanks; but I could not follow you completely; (see, If we take, $2<y <3$, then $[y]-1=1$, and $[y]+2=4,$ now, if $[y]+2\leq n \leq \infty,$ then, my question is how are you getting, $\frac{1}{1+(n-y)^{2}}\leq \frac{1}{1+n^{2}}$ ?; actually, I am getting the reverse way, see, in this case, $n-y<n,$ and so, $(n-y)^{2}\leq n^{2}$; therefore, $\frac{1}{1+(n-y)^{2}}\geq \frac{1}{1+n^{2}}$; please correct me if I am wrong here;) so would you please tell me bit more here; thanks;

Comment: when $n = [y] - i$, then $(n-y)^2 = ([y]-i -y)^2 \geq i^2$, thus, $\frac{1}{1+(n-y)^2} \leq \frac{1}{1+i^2}$, similary for $n = [y]+1 + i$

Comment: yes, then you make the sum

Comment: thanks; this slightly different but related, if we put, $I(y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{1+n^{2}}{1+(n-y)^{r}};$ so can we expect to find large $r$ so that, $I(y)\leq C (1+y^{2})$ for all $y\in \mathbb R$ and $C$ is a constant? Thanks for every thing;

Answer (score 2):

The value of 
$$ f(y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{1+(n-y)^2}$$
obviously depends only on $\{y\}$, and $f(y)$ is a regular periodic function with period $1$. We have:

> $$ f(y) = \frac{\pi \sinh(2\pi)}{\cosh(2\pi)+\cos(2\pi y)}$$

so $f(y)$ is bounded between:
$$ 3.129881\ldots=\pi\tanh\pi \leq f(y) \leq \pi\coth\pi = 3.153348\ldots$$